# Automatically mark questions with SQL injections vulnerabilities

Tags: feature-request, comments

[A live list of SQL injection vulnerabilities in Stack Overflow posts](https://laurent22.github.io/so-injections/) was trending on Hacker News a few days ago. I immediately felt the urge to click on all the questions and alert the author to the problem.

Is it constructive to do that?

Should I write a script that does just this?

Shouldn't Stack Overflow just include a feature that somehow flags/marks questions in a way that is visible for the question author and all future visitors? This could prevent unsuspecting people from copy-pasting blindly.

Comment: You want to prevent people from copy-pasting blindly by writing a script that blindly leaves comments to thousands of questions? How ironic!

Comment: There's http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164926/179419 and the 5 questions it links to.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338065/can-we-get-rid-of-little-bobby-tables

Comment: Did the question have vulnerabilities, or answers on those questions? There is a bit of a difference. Questions with vulnerabilities are kind of expected, but answers with vulnerabilities potentially deserve downvotes and a better answer to outshine them.

Comment: @Gimby the questions specifically.

Comment: @CodyGray no, I want to find a way to alert the question authors of the problem in a better way than writing a script that blindly leaves comments. That is specifically why I'm asking.

Comment: The community is already doing this. Over half of the most recent questions on that page already have a comment warning about SQL injections.

Comment: For a precedent regarding the negative backlash you might expect to encounter if you post comments in a short period of time on multiple questions with the same fatal flaw, see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318885/fixing-answers-that-recommend-chmod-777). Note that here, Carpetsmoker didn't even use a script. He left the comments by hand, and a moderator still thought fit to remove them. The community's support for that was divided, but still something to keep in mind.

Comment: With a name like that, why would you care?

Answer (score 15):

Don't do that. Especially not in any "automated" manner.

A large portion of those results seem to assume variables dumped into a query aren't sanitized. The search seems to err on the side of (paranoid) caution.

For the portion of results that *are* vulnerabilities, the vulnerability might well be part of the question / answer.

---

Users are responsible for the code they blindly copy-paste. Stack Overflow is not.

Comment: "A massive portion of those results seem to assume variables dumped into a query aren't sanitized. The search seems to err on the side of (paranoid) caution." I'd say it errs on the side of two decades of evidence. Sanitizing variables is not a reliable approach.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Okay, I may have exaggerated it a bit, but the algorithm will most likely still return a significant number of false positives where an automated comment would be misplaced, right?

Comment: Automated comments are a very questionable approach, yes. I don't have a good solution, I'm just frustrated by the situation.

Comment: I guess any effort to fix SQL injection should start at the source: documentation / book. Ambitious? Sure.

Comment: With each new wave of devs, this problem will continue to arrise regardless of what we do. I find comments pointing out sql vulnerabilities to be mostly unconstructive noise due to 90% of the time having nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @KevinB I see somewhat reverse proportion - 90% of questions related to SQL in C# are due to using string concatenation to build SQL queries... For the rest there is always "Close as missing MCVE" - if querying SQL is not related to the problem it should not be in the question to start with or should have query with constant values (and 90% of statistics made up on the spot:) )